# Azure API Management Retirement Issue

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have few question to Azure API Management... If not mistaken starting from 30 September 2023, all API versions for the Azure API Management service prior to 2021-08-01 will be retired and API calls using those API versions will fail. I have checked my API version mostly used as 2019-12-01 ...

How can I update my version with any easier way without complicated

Answer (score 0):

You should only be concerned if you're making calls to ARM to manage APIM service using older SDKs or manual REST calls with older API versions. All internal dependencies even if use older API versions will not be affected.